# How can I display Image if my list is empty?

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

I want to display an Image or Text in Center like `No Record Found` all details are fetched from API. In Native Android `setEmptyView()` for this condition but no idea how can I do this in flutter. Non-stop progress Dialog is running but the text is not displayed. I added code with my JSON response

```
List<NewAddressModel> newAddress = List();
bool isLoading = false;

Scaffold(
body :isLoading
          ? Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
          : Container(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(234, 236, 238, 1),
          child: getListView()
      ),
)
```

```
Widget getListView(){
    return newAddress.isNotEmpty ?
    ListView.builder(itemCount: newAddress.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return addressViewCard(index);
        }

    )
        : Center(child: Text("No Found"));
  }
```

```
Future<List>hitGetAddressApi() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    final response = await http.post(api);

    var userDetails = json.decode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      newAddress = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
          .map((data) => new NewAddressModel.fromJson(data))
          .toList();
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        newAddressModel = new NewAddressModel.fromJson(userDetails[0]);
      });
    }


    return userDetails;
  }
```

```
This is JSON Response which I am getting from my API.
[
    {
        "id": "35",
        "name": "Toyed",
        "mobile": "8855226611",
        "address": "House No 100",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "city": "New Delhi",
        "pin": "000000",
        "userid": "2",
    }
]
```

Comment: did you check you are getting correct response. i mean status code 200 ?

Comment: You can have a boolean variable which holds state if your api is loading and when you get response from api turn that to false and show other view, so in your scaffold you can check that variable and show view accordingly

Comment: Yes If I add an item I am getting a response but when I deleted all details then this happens progress dialog is  running non-stoppable

Comment: Tell me if you can't understand that

Comment: If my JSON response is null or list is empty then It Shows no record found in the center.

Comment: Use a futurebuilder with future as result of api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyWidget()));

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Future<List<NewAddressModel>> newAddress;

  @override
  void initState() {
    newAddress = hitGetAddressApi();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<NewAddressModel>> hitGetAddressApi() async {
    final response = await http.post("api");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseBody is List)
        return responseBody
            .map((data) => new NewAddressModel.fromJson(data))
            .toList();
      else {
        print(responseBody);
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw Exception("Problem in fetching address List");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<NewAddressModel>>(
        future: newAddress,
        builder: (context, snapShot) {
          if (snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          else if (snapShot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("ERROR: ${snapShot.error}"),
            );
          } else {
            if (snapShot.hasData && snapShot.data.isNotEmpty)
              return getListView(snapShot.data);
            else //`snapShot.hasData` can be false if the `snapshot.data` is null
              return Center(
                child: Text("No Data Found"),
              );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getListView(List<NewAddressModel> addressList) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: addressList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final address = addressList[index];
        //Change `addressViewCard` to accept an `NewAddressModel` object
        return addressViewCard(address);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget addressViewCard(NewAddressModel address) {
    //implement based on address instead of index
    return ListTile(title: Text("${address.address}"));
  }
}

class NewAddressModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  String mobile;
  String address;
  String state;
  String city;
  String pin;
  String userid;

  NewAddressModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.mobile,
    this.address,
    this.state,
    this.city,
    this.pin,
    this.userid,
  });

  factory NewAddressModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      NewAddressModel(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        mobile: json["mobile"],
        address: json["address"],
        state: json["state"],
        city: json["city"],
        pin: json["pin"],
        userid: json["userid"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "mobile": mobile,
        "address": address,
        "state": state,
        "city": city,
        "pin": pin,
        "userid": userid,
      };
}
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: This exception is occurs

Comment: @Toyed Is the response body a list? Can you add example json response in your question?

Comment: Yes, I am adding

Comment: @Toyed I added code with `NewAddressModel` class. if you get the same error then add that log too. thank you

Comment: This time getting this error . ERROR : NoSuchMethodError : The method ' map ' was called on null . Receiver : null Tried calling : map < NewAddressModel > ( Closure : ( dynamic ) = > NewAddressModel )

Comment: @Toyed I think your server sending `null` response. in the previous error it may have sent a` `map` try printing `response.body`

Comment: API returns ```{"message":"No Data Found"}``` when I hit it in Postman but when I try to print ```response.body``` nothing is displaying the same pervious error occurs

Comment: I am not sure why the server returning 200 response for "No data found".

Comment: @Toyed I updated the code. Understand how to handle response body data and json convert. then you can manipulate them easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207280/discussion-between-toyed-and-crazy-lazy-cat).

Comment: hey can you help me in this query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433200/how-to-make-dependent-multilevel-dropdown-in-flutter

Answer (score 2):

I would like to tell you that please use `FutureBuilder` for this kind of usage.
In your code i am not sure where you are changing state of `isLoading` flag.

So please update your question, and please be sure that you are changing `isLoading` flag in proper scope.

Please refer [this](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9) for implementation of  `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to use `FutureBuilder` here you have all sorts of checks

Answer (score 2):

```
FutureBuilder<AsyncSnapshot<AsyncSnapshot>>(
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            return Text("loading");
          } else {
            if (snap.hasError) {
              return Text([snap.error.toString()]); 
            }
            else {
              if (snap.hasData) {


                return getListView("${snap.data}");
              } else {
                return Text("No DAta");
              }
            }
          }
        },
        future:
        methodToGetAPIResult(),
    );
```

Comment: Every time execute error block if no data in the list.

Comment: Please explain what happens

Comment: Every time this ```if (snap.hasError) {
              return Text([snap.error.toString()]); 
            }``` block executed.

Comment: If my list is null

Comment: what is output of [snap.error.toString()] in this case as it seems there is an error in getting snap

Answer (score 1):

You have to use different `widget` for this. You can use something like this to display empty image when there is no data.

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if (array.isEmpty()) {
            return Widget(child: Thing(this.name));
        } else {
            return Widget(child: WithoutThing(this.name));
        }
    }
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: @Dev check now.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the best solution will be the use of [**FutureBuilder**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder/FutureBuilder.html) .

The [FutureBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

[An article that can help you](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9)